# Meteor JS & Blaze - Show Only Once on Load

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a partial that show's a notification modal to agree to the site's terms and service that I would only like to show once (once they click I agree it goes away).

Is there anyway to do that with Meteor?

Comment: Do you want to combine this with user accounts system or is it just more browser related, e.g. "I accept the cookies policy" thing.

Comment: Cookies policy. User shouldn't be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to store a boolean in the DB indicating that the user has accepted the terms (so they never get asked again), you could add a field called `hasAcceptedTerms` somewhere on the user object (e.g. in the user's profile). Once you do that you could write your template like this:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#if areTermsVisible}}
    (put terms partial here)
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Where `areTermsVisible` looks like:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  areTermsVisible: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    return user && user.profile && !user.profile.hasAcceptedTerms;
  }
});
```

And the code to record the acceptance looks like:

```js
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .accept-terms': function() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    var modifier = {$set: {'profile.hasAcceptedTerms': true}};
    Meteor.users.update(userId, modifier);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not surprisingly, the best way to deal with cookies policy notification is by using cookies. The problem is not meteor-specific, but there are at least two good atmosphere packages that can help you to deal with the problem:

https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/cookies

https://atmospherejs.com/chuangbo/cookie

What you need to do is basically, set cookie

```
Cookie.set('userHasAcceptedPolicy', true, { year: 1 });
```

with whatever arguments you like, and as soon as the user clicks the "accept" button. Then, before you decide if you need to show the policy notification you can use:

```
Cookies.get('userHasAcceptedPolicy');
```

to see if there's a need to do so. So it's pretty much the same solution as @DavidWeldon suggested but it does not require referencing the `Meteor.user()` object, so the user does not need to have an account to accept the policy.

Please note, that - at least in case of `mrt:cookies` - `Cookies.get` is a [reactive data source](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity), which is quite helpful when it comes to rendering templates.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of ways...

This isn't a Meteor specific question.

```
Template.notifications.events({
  'click #close-modal': function(e, t) {
    $('#modal').hide();
  }
})
```